# php array sort lower-case first

Tags: php, sorting

I search for a solution to sort an array only that the lower-case are first. I know the order from regex [A-Za-z0-9]. I like the order [a-zA-Z0-9]. case-insensitive sort is not a solution for this.

1. Normaly sort from scandir():

   - A001.TXT
   - B002.TXT
   - C003.TXT
   - X004.TXT
   - Y005.txt
   - Z006.TXT
   - a001.txt
   - b002.TXT
   - c003.txt
   - x004.txt
   - y005.TXT
   - z006.txt
   - 0001.TXT
   - 1001.txt
   - 2001.TXT
2. I like this sort:

   - a001.txt
   - b002.TXT
   - c003.txt
   - x004.txt
   - y005.TXT
   - z006.txt
   - A001.TXT
   - B002.TXT
   - C003.TXT
   - X004.TXT
   - Y005.txt
   - Z006.TXT
   - 0001.TXT
   - 1001.txt
   - 2001.TXT

Comment: You can use `usort()` and implement any comparation function You like.

Comment: ideally all file extensions in a directory should all be one case --  Since technically speaking `a001.txt` and `a001.TXT` are two separate files with the same naming convention prior to the extension.  1) this would solve your issue and 2) it will alleviate more confusion in the future should two files be named the same thing with different cases on the extension.  Also, just in case you are using uppercase and lowercase of the same extension  to differentiate between files - Don't.  This is also bad practice and a more thorough naming convention should be established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `usort()` here with a custom comparator function:

```
$arr = array(...);
function getOrder($input) {
    $order = 4;
    if (preg_match("/^[a-z]/", $input)) {
        $order = 1;
    }
    else if (preg_match("/^[A-Z]/", $input)) {
        $order = 2;
    }
    else if (preg_match("/^[0-9]/", $input)) {
        $order = 3;
    }
    else {
        $order = 4;
    }

    return $order;
}

usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    $a_order = getOrder($a);
    $b_order = getOrder($b);

    if ($a_order == $b_order) {
        return strcmp($a, $b);
    }

    if ($a_order < $b_order) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
});

$print_r($arr);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a001.txt
    [1] => b002.TXT
    [2] => c003.txt
    [3] => x004.txt
    [4] => y005.TXT
    [5] => z006.txt
    [6] => A001.TXT
    [7] => B002.TXT
    [8] => C003.TXT
    [9] => X004.TXT
    [10] => Y005.txt
    [11] => Z006.TXT
    [12] => 0001.TXT
    [13] => 1001.txt
    [14] => 2001.TXT
)
```

The strategy here is to use the `getOrder()` function to determine whether a filename begin with a lowercase, uppercase, or number.  For each of these cases, we assign a priority, increasing in that order.  Then, in the lambda comparator function used with `usort()`, we compare the priorities of the two incoming filenames.  Note that for the case where two filenames happen to start with the same type (e.g. both lowercase), we fall back to `strcmp()` to determine which comes first.

Comment: aha. so it works usort(). there is no pre-built function available for this? I like a PHP pre-built func like regexsort($array, '[a-zA-Z0-9]'). And than i will edit my question to regexsort($array, '[0-9a-zA-Z]'), because origin regex is [0-9A-Za-z] like ASCII order.

Comment: @Malama You actually want _reverse_ ASCII order based on the first letter class (digit, uppercase, lowercase), but within each class, it should be sorted ascending by ASCII.